# Syntax Error in Query Field Definition

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I'm trying to create a table in ms-access at runtime when using VB6. I keep getting an error saying that there is a syntax error in the field definition, but I can't see one anywhere.

```
"CREATE TABLE PickedByPicco(OrderID INT, StockCode TEXT(30), Qty CURRENCY, ScannedBy TEXT, " & _
                "ProcessedBy TEXT, processed BOOLEAN, Constraint compKey PRIMARY KEY(OrderID, StockCode))"
```

Where is the error in this query? Is it something to do with the primary key perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name for a boolean yes/no field in Access is `BIT`, not `BOOLEAN`.

Use the following:

```
"CREATE TABLE PickedByPicco(OrderID INT, StockCode TEXT(30), Qty CURRENCY, ScannedBy TEXT, " & _
                "ProcessedBy TEXT, processed BIT, Constraint compKey PRIMARY KEY(OrderID, StockCode))"
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it!

Comment: Synonyms are BIT, LOGICAL, LOGICAL1, and YESNO.